# Override cached image in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, caching

I have an ajax response that is returning images that are cached. I can bust this cache with a random number generator, but having an issue applying it correctly to the returned URI.

The cached image has a URI coming from the response represented by "*obj.entity.entries[property].uri*" that looks like this: 
`http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d?location=SQUARE`

The newly uploaded image needs to have the random number applied to it, so that it is appended to the end of the URI, right before the `?`, like so:
`http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d`+6`?location=SQUARE`, where `+6` is the randomly generated number.

I believe the best approach is to use a regex to look for the end of the URI before the `?` and apply the var storing the random number, then reapply this new URI to the response. I have the following worked out, but not sure how to apply the regex correctly:

```
$('.image-search').on('click', function () {
    var root = "http://localhost:7777/proxy/staging/rest/v1/cms/story/id/";
    var encodeID = $("#imageid").val();
    var bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
    var imageCacheBust = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    //IF TESTING ON LOCALHOST
    if (document.domain == 'localhost') {
        url = root + encodeID + "/images";
    } else {
        //IF IN PRODUCTION
        url = "/cropper/admin/cropv2/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + encodeID + "/images";
        //GRAB REFERRER URL FOR VIMOND ASSET 
        //SET VALUE SUCCEEDING ASSETS AS ASSET ID
        var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
        var assetid = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
        $("#imageid").val(assetid[1]);
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": bearerToken
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        var obj = response;
        var regexp = "REGEX HERE";
        var imageURI = regexp.exec(obj.entity.entries[property].uri);
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
        $(".search-results").empty();
        for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
            if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
            }
        }
    }).fail(function (data) {
        $(".search-results").empty();
        $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why add left of the `?`, just add it after. E.g: `img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d?location=SQUARE&6`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add your random digits to the file path part of the URL, just append to the URL parameters instead, that is enough to prevent caching.

For example use:

```
img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d?location=SQUARE&6
```

Where the `6` is your randomly generated value.

Also, be aware that a randomly generated number might not be the best choice here, since it might be undesirably duplicated. Consider using a hash or timestamp instead of a purely random number.

Comment: I update my code to use 

`var date = new Date();
        var imageCacheBust = date.getSeconds();`

However, I have three orientations being returned: PORTRAIT, SQUARE and LANDSCAPE. The portrait is returned without `?location=SQUARE` or `?location=LANDSCAPE` at the end of the URL. So with this implementation, I can't get the portrait image back for some reason.

Comment: I tried: 
`if(obj.entity.entries[property].orientation == 'PORTRAIT'){
                        var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + imageCacheBust;
                    }`, but its actually not showing the portrait image.

Comment: I added it like so: `if(obj.entity.entries[property].orientation == 'PORTRAIT'){
                        var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "&" + imageCacheBust;
                    }`, but it had no affect.

Comment: Try perhaps this: `obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "&time=" + imageCacheBust;`

Comment: To clarify, the images being returned in the JSON are formatted with `?location=SQUARE` and `?location=LANDSCAPE` for square and landscape, but the portrait image does not have this at the end of its URI.

Comment: Another option, since I can pull in all three images without a conditional check of the orientation, would be to just slice off the `&(number here)` at the end. I've tried `.truncate()`, but can't get it right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being fairly simple:

I set `var imageCacheBust = Math.random();` and then used it in the returned URI like so: `var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "?" + imageCacheBust;`